# How is しまえば used? In what context and how it should translated to?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, translation

Was reading a light novel and this sentence popped up:

> ここまで動{うご}いてしまえば、フューネラルに気付{きづ}かれるのも時間の問題かもしれません。

フューネラル refers to an organisation within the light novel setting.

I'm confused by the usage of しまえば. Scouring the net, it seems to imply the meaning of "(something) is true", but there seems to be nothing like a translation or usage guide on this. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

してしまう = to end up doing.

Thus I would translate:

ここまで動いてしまえば -> Now that having ended up moving like this

フューネラルに気付かれるのも時間の問題かもしれません -> it may be a matter of time that we are detected by Funeral

Comment: The explanation might be a little confusing, grammar-wise. I think you should note that しまえば is the conditional conjugation. While your example is technically correct, its conditional is kind of implicit going into the succeeding clause ("now that x" sets up a case conditional). Perhaps follow the construct of "if x ends up doing" for the translation?